# var inside of brackets

Tags: python, syntax

I have this ....

```
   fileExt = {'png': "'Content-Type': 'image/png'", 'jpe': "'Content-Type':
   'image/jpeg'", 'jpg': "'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg'", 
   'png': "Content-Type': 'image/png'", 'mp4': "'Content-Type': 'video/mpeg'",
   'mp3': "'Content-Type': 'audio/mpeg'", '3gp': "'Content-Type': 'video/3gpp'",
   'flv': "'Content-Type': 'video/x-flv'", 'flv': "'Content-Type': 'video/x-flv'"}
   handler = fileExt.get(ext)
   go = "'"+handler
   key.copy(key.bucket, key.name, preserve_acl=True, metadata={go})
```

i'm getting this error...

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "s3ContentType.py", line 43, in <module>
   key.copy(key.bucket, key.name, preserve_acl=True, metadata={go})
  File "/task/__pips__/boto/s3/key.py", line 474, in copy
   encrypt_key=encrypt_key)
  File "/task/__pips__/boto/s3/bucket.py", line 723, in copy_key
   headers = boto.utils.merge_meta(headers, metadata, provider)
  File "/task/__pips__/boto/utils.py", line 172, in merge_meta
   for k in metadata.keys():
AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

But if i explicitly put a string inside the metadata brackets it works.

```
  key.copy(key.bucket, key.name, preserve_acl=True, metadata={'Content-Type': 'image/png'})
```

What gives, how do i include a var inside the brackets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a nested dictionary as well for keeping file extensions and content like this

```
    fileExt = {'png': {'Content-Type': 'image/png'}, 'jpe': {'Content-Type':'image/jpeg'}, 
    'jpg': {'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg'}, 'png': {'Content-Type': 'image/png'}, 
    'mp4': {'Content-Type': 'video/mpeg'}, 'mp3': {'Content-Type': 'audio/mpeg'}, 
    '3gp': {'Content-Type': 'video/3gpp'}, 'flv': {'Content-Type': 'video/x-flv'}, 
    'flv': {'Content-Type': 'video/x-flv'}}
    handler = fileExt.get(ext)
```

then you will be directly using handler in metadata, like this

```
    key.copy(key.bucket, key.name, preserve_acl=True, metadata=handler)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are constructing two different objects here:

```
foo = {'a', 'b', 'c'}
```

is a [set](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset), while

```
bar = {'a': 'b', 'c': 'd'}
```

is a [dictionary](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict). You can of course reference variables when constructing a dict:

```
mimetype = "image/png"
bar = {'Content-Type': mimetype}
```

A dictionary maps keys to values (hence the `:`), while the set is only a collection of distinct values. The funciton you're calling expects a dictionary, so you have to create one. If you have a dictionary and want to pass that (continuing from above), you can do that like this:

```
mimetype = "image/png"
bar = {'Content-Type': mimetype}
key.copy(key.bucket, key.name, preserve_acl=True, metadata=bar)
```

(note that the links go to python 3 documentation, but sets and dicts have not really changed since python 2)

---

For the edit: As the accepted answer said, you have to use a nested dictionary. The question is, why doesn't it work otherwise?

Otherwise, you're creating a set containing the string you previously stored in the fileExt dictionary, for example "Content-Type: 'image/png'". Python will not interpret this string, which is why it does not create a dictionary when you write `{"Content-Type: 'image/png'"}`.

Comment: can you check out the edited question....i tried key.copy(key.bucket, key.name, preserve_acl=True, metadata=go) and got this error key.copy(key.bucket, key.name, preserve_acl=True, metadata=go)

Answer (score 1):

When you say `{go}` you are actually creating a `set`, not a `dict`. And sets don't have keys.

```
print type({"Welcome"})
print type({"1":"Welcome"})
```

**Output**

```
<type 'set'>
<type 'dict'>
```

But when you say `{'Content-Type': 'image/png'}`, you are actually creating a `dict` and thats why it works.